# Python curses confusing keypad() SIGINT behaviour

Tags: python, curses

I have a piece of code that uses curses in Python 2.7. What I can understand is that `getch()` is giving me SIGINT's value as -1. But I want to understand following behaviour in bit more detail:

**Case #1**
Consider this piece of code:

```
myscreen = curses.initscr()

def end(sig,frame):
    myscreen.addstr(1,0,'sigint')
    c=myscreen.getch()
    myscreen.addstr(2,0,str(c))
    myscreen.getch()
    curses.endwin()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,end)
myscreen.addstr('waiting...')
myscreen.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

The output I get is:

```
waiting...
sigint #This I get after first SIGINT
-1 #This I get after second SIGINT
```

After another key press, the program ends. So it took 3 key press.

**Case #2**
Consider this code:

```
myscreen = curses.initscr()
myscreen.keypad(1)

def end(sig,frame):
    myscreen.addstr(1,0,'sigint')
    c=myscreen.getch()
    myscreen.addstr(2,0,str(c))
    myscreen.getch()
    curses.endwin()
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,end)
myscreen.addstr('waiting...')
myscreen.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

Output is:

```
waiting...
sigint
-1 #This I get after first SIGINT
```

After another key press, program ends. This took only 2 inputs and we had -1 in output right after first SIGINT, which means first `getch()` in `end()` automatically got input of -1 (which seems to be SIGINT from case #1) somehow. Can anyone please explain what presence of `keypad()` function is doing? Is this something related to how escape character is treated with `keypad()`?

Comment: If you really need to know, you'll have to study the source-code, e.g., for ncurses (which is where the Python code calls).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Though I'm interested in finding the answer, I'm not that much committed that I'd go through the source code for that. :p